# Airflow: Set dag to not be automatically scheduled

Tags: airflow

When I create a new dag, I have to go into the UI and click on the 'schedule' toggle to turn scheduling off.  How can I do this without needing to use the UI?  Is there an option in the DAG constructor itself?

[image: airflow scheduling button]

In other words: how do I turn those buttons above to 'Off' in my DAG file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to set a DAG as disabled within a DAG file. You can mimic the behavior by temporarily setting the DAG's `schedule_interval` to `None`. You can also set the airflow configuration value `dags_are_paused_at_creation` to `True` if you want to make sure all new DAGs to be off by default. You'll need to then turn new DAGs on manually in the UI when they are ready to be scheduled.

Answer (score 5):

you can set the `is_paused_upon_creation=True`

```
    DAG(dag_id=dag_id,
        schedule_interval='@once',
         ...
        is_paused_upon_creation=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to set this within the DAG file, but if you're trying to enable or disable a large amount of DAGs you can run an UPDATE statement in your Airflow database: `UPDATE dag SET is_paused = TRUE;`